# how can I display my file name using PDF.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am trying to display a PDF document using pdf.js.

I am able to display also the number of pages, current page, etc. But couldn't figure how to display file name!here's my code:

```
<div id="pdf-title"></div>
<div id="page-count-container">Page
    <div id="pdf-current-page"></div> of <div id="pdf-total-pages">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
..
<script>
    ..
    var title;
    var __PDF_DOC,
        __CURRENT_PAGE,
        __TOTAL_PAGES,
        __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0,
        __CANVAS = $('#pdf-canvas').get(0),
        __CANVAS_CTX = __CANVAS.getContext('2d');


    function showPDF(pdf_url) {
        $("#pdf-loader").show();

        PDFJS.getDocument({
            url: pdf_url
        }).then(function(pdf_doc) {
            __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
            __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;
            title = __PDF_DOC._filename;

            // Hide the pdf loader and show pdf container in HTML
            $("#pdf-loader").hide();
            $("#pdf-contents").show();
            $("#pdf-total-pages").text(__TOTAL_PAGES);
            $("#pdf-title").text(toString(title));

            // Show the first page
            showPage(1);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // If error re-show the upload button
            $("#pdf-loader").hide();
            $("#upload-button").show();

            alert(error.message);
        });;
    }..
</script>
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to fix this inconvenience, here's my code:

```
var __PDF_DOC,
    __CURRENT_PAGE,
    __TOTAL_PAGES,
    __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0,
    __CANVAS = $('#pdf-canvas').get(0),
    __TITLE;
    __CANVAS_CTX = __CANVAS.getContext('2d');


function showPDF(pdf_url) {
    $("#pdf-loader").show();

    PDFJS.getDocument({ url: pdf_url }).then(function(pdf_doc) {
        __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
        __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;
        __TITLE=$("#file-to-upload").get(0).files[0].name;

        // Hide the pdf loader and show pdf container in HTML
        $("#pdf-loader").hide();
        $("#pdf-contents").show();
        $("#pdf-total-pages").text(__TOTAL_PAGES);
        $("#pdf-title").text(__TITLE);
```

i was calling actually for the wrong variable!! hope this would help some of you guys!!